# Weird Facebook Bug on Galaxy S6 Edge

Tags: facebook

Does anyone experience this problem?

The videos on posts are floating bellow from where they should be, covering the comments count:

[image]

There is an weird space left there, it happens for all posts with embedded videos.

If I scroll down further the video disappears and the comments show up:

[image]

I've tried to uninstall ( can't really because facebook comes preinstaled, can only deactivate), cleaning the app data and wipe the cache partition, but no success.

Comment: This font seems large to me. Does the presentation clear up if a smaller system fontsize is employed? Settings >Display >Font size

Comment: What Facebook app build version are you using? Haven't such bug in 122.0.0.17.71

Comment: Have you reached out to Facebook? If it's legitimately a bug in the app then you'll need to engage Facebook support to try to get it fixed.